# Edit and Save results from Microsoft Access in C#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, textbox

I am working on my own POS system and I use this code to try and make the application edit the "quantity" of the item. What I did was I have a search bar where I can search the Barcode ID and the data will show up in the textbox. (IE: The original quantity will show up in textBox1. I would get that textBox.Text + "1" [**I am not going to go into detail here but it works, please comment if you do need the code**]). Now I want to link and edit the data to the Access database and insert the result from the second textbox(that has the original textbox +1)
Here is the error:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEEFe.png)

Here is the code:

```
       using System.Data.OleDb;
       using System.Drawing.Printing;
       using System.IO;
       using System.Drawing.Imaging;

       namespace TestBarcode
                {
                        public partial class POS : Form
                {
          private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();


    public POS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString=@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\POS\Database\MainDatabase_POS.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";
    }

        private void POS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          this.inventoryManagementTableAdapter.Fill(this.mainDatabase_POSDataSet.InventoryManagement);
        checkBox1.Show();
        checkBox2.Hide();
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select * from InventoryManagement";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
     }


  try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;

   //EditTextHere

           string query = "UPDATE InventoryManagement set Số_Lượng_Trong_Kho='" + textBox25.Text + "',Mã_Số_Vạch='" + textBox19.Text + "',Mã_thợ='" + textBox13.Text + "',Kiểu='" + textBox14.Text + "',Size_Giày='" + textBox15.Text + "',Màu='" + textBox16.Text + "',Giá='" + textBox17.Text + "'where ID=" + textBox24.Text + "";

command.CommandText = query;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(query);

            connection.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
```

PS: (1) Ignore the Vietnamese text, you can replace those words with anything if you like.

(2) Sorry, I kind of screwed up with the textbox so the name of the textbox is random and very hard to understand.

Is there a way to make this happen? If so,  please help. Thanks.

Comment: When you put a variable between single quotes as you do in the Update command then that is passed to your database engine as a string. If the engine expects something different then it could try to convert your 'string' to the expected value. Sometime it works, sometime no. Start using parameters and specify exactly your datatypes.

Comment: Will it work if I select the datarow and then specify out  which datarow it is and then edit the one I have chosen? 

Like this:

     foreach (DataRow db in dt.Rows)
                  {
                      ,,,,,
                  }

Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are passing wrong data type of parameters. Please check the data types of the values passed from textboxes & the columns of the database table. I am sure there will be some miss match.